# Access SQL: Select most recent date rather than list of dates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of commodity prices and price dates and another table with supplier transaction data that also has a column with dates. The price dates and supplier dates column are not identical. If I pick a date from the supplier table, I want to retrieve the commodity price of the date closest to that supplier transaction date. The commodity price date can be before or equal to the supplier transaction date but not later than this date.

WORKING ANSWER:
[List3 is the possible supplier dates and List4 is the commodity]

```
SELECT TOP 1 CommPrices.Price
FROM CommPrices
WHERE (((CommPrices.DateComm)<=[Forms]![Tool Should Cost]![List3]) AND ((CommPrices.Commodity)=[Forms]![Tool Should Cost]![List4]))
ORDER BY CommPrices.DateComm DESC;
```

Example of what I want:

Assume there is the commodity copper with the following date and price data:
**01/01/2015  $10.00 & 01/01/2016 $5.00 & 06/06/2016 $15.00**

If I select a random supplier date at lets say february first 2016, then the most recent date is 01/01/2016 and thus I should retrieve $5.

Comment: I removed the "mysql" tag because the syntax strongly suggests MS Access.

Comment: It is Ms Access - sorry about that

Comment: No. Just the most recent commodity price, closest to the selected supplier date.

Comment: Yes - sorry about that. I edited the post.

Comment: Why did you discard `ORDER BY CommPrices.DateComm DESC`?

Comment: It got lost in my copying/pasting - the final code works now. Thanks Gordon and Hans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CommPrices.Price
FROM CommPrices
WHERE CommPrices.DateComm <= [Forms]![Tool Should Cost]![List 3]
ORDER BY CommPrices.DateComm DESC;
```

Comment: That gives me the error: The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

Comment: Remove parentheses -> `SELECT TOP 1`

Comment: The code runs but does not give me correct information. I tested it and it gave me back a much larger number - For example, I tested it for commodity cobalt and selected date 9/1/2015. The price of cobalt that day was $28,398.26 dollars yet the query gives me $92.521,10. It actually gives this last number for any supplier date I select.